How to round to ones place with siunitx table-format, e.g. "-1e-12"
I want to format numbers like -9.9309e-13 to show as -1e-12.  I've tried to do this, below, but it's not working.  What am I missing?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{U}{S[
   table-format=-1.0e-2, round-precision=0,scientific-notation=true,
   output-exponent-marker=\text{e}, exponent-product={},
   round-mode=places
]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{U}
-9.2226e-13 \\
-9.9309e-13 \\
1.1200e-13 \\
5.5216e-12 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Result is
−9e−13
−1.0e−12
 1e−13
 6e−12

Desired result is
−9e−13
−1e−12
 1e−13
 6e−12


You need to provide the option drop-zero-decimal=true. (The default value of the drop-zero-decimal flag is false.)

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{U}{S[
      table-format          = -1.0e-2, 
      round-precision       = 0,
      scientific-notation   = true,
      output-exponent-marker= \mathrm{e}, 
      exponent-product      = {},
      round-mode            = places,
      drop-zero-decimal     = true % <-- new
      ]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{U}
-9.2226e-13 \\
-9.9309e-13 \\
 1.1200e-13 \\
 9.9309e-13 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


Now I see it in the siunitx manual, "It may be desirable to convert decimals to integers when the decimal part is zero. This is set up using the drop-zero-decimal option, which applies after rounding but before setting minimum numbers of digits."
